# How do I cube/square a logarithm?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, roots

Btw, please don't give me the answer. I just wanna know how to raise a logarithm to its cube cause I'm stuck in this part, but don't solve it for me.

$$\log \sqrt[3]x = \sqrt[3]{\log x}$$
I tried different ways but. When I input the values in my calculator, it just doesn't match.

My answer: is it right?
  $$1/3\log x =\sqrt[3]{\log x}$$
  $$\log x = 3\sqrt[3]{\log x}$$
  $$a = 3\sqrt[3]{\log x}$$
  $$a^3 = \log x^{27} $$
  $$\log x^3 = \log x^{27}$$
  $$\log x^{24} = 0$$
  $$ x = \sqrt[24]{1}$$
  $$ x = 1$$

Comment: Did you want to write something like $\log\sqrt[3]{x}=\sqrt[3]{\log x}$? This can be obtained as `$\log\sqrt[3]{x}=\sqrt[3]{\log x}$`. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: i copied and pasted what you posted. it didnt work. BTW that is my question

Comment: Did you also copy the dollar signs, and did *not* prefix it with four spaces?

Comment: Try $a = 3\sqrt[3]{a}$ and cube both sides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write $\log \sqrt[3] x$ in terms of $\log x$ using the laws of logarithms. So substitute $u=\log x$ and solve for $u$ (after rearranging you have a cubic equation in $u$) then substitute back and solve for $x$.

---

**Edit:** Your error in your working is thinking that $a^3 = \log x^3$. In fact, $a^3 = (\log  x)^3$.

Comment: Tried it man! not sure if I did it correctly though.. the calculator says its right. But both of the sides are equal to zero so its kinda fishy.

Comment: @vincentbelkin: Show your working if you're stuck. I think the problem here might be that you're using a calculator! EDIT: also see the edit to my post.

Comment: i posted it in the original question man, I only use my calculator to check..

Comment: I edited my post. When you substitute $a=\log x$, substitute it *throughout*, not just for one instance of $\log x$. Then solve for $a$, and *then* sub back and solve for $x$; that way you will make fewer errors. In fact, $x=1$ *is* one solution, but there are more that you missed in error.

Comment: but how do i cube root logx^(27)? Thats the part im stuck with.

Comment: You're on the wrong track. Let me start you off. You know that $\log \sqrt[3]{x} = \frac{1}{3}\log x$, so the equation $\log \sqrt[3]{x} = \sqrt[3]{\log x}$ becomes $\frac{1}{3}u = \sqrt[3]{u}$ when we substitute $u=\log x$. Forget $x$ for now and just solve this for $u$. Then substitute back and solve for $x$. [You seem to be repeatedly making the error of thinking that $(\log x)^a = \log (x^a)$ - this is not the case.]

Comment: Ok so using that, I got x = 10^(sqrt(27)) which is right but, I never got 1, which is also a solution?

Comment: @vincentbelkin: In that case my guess is that you did some dividing, rather than factorising. You should get to $u^3=27u$, right? There are $3$ possible values $u$ can take. To find them all, factorise the expression.

Answer (score 4):

1) Remember that $\,\log x^n=n\log x\,$

2) Now just note that $\,\log \sqrt[3] x=\log x^{1/3}\,$

Anyways, it is *not* true in general that $\,\log \sqrt[3] x=\sqrt[3]{\log x}\,$

Answer (score 0):

$\log$ is not so friendly with square/cube roots.., i.e. your identity is not true in general. Are you looking for its solution $x$?

Do you know that $\sqrt[3]x=x^{\frac13}$?

Comment: With odd roots it is just fine. Problems can arise with even roots if we're not sufficiently careful.

Comment: Posted an answer man! not sure if its right though

Answer (score 0):

One method you may attempt; when you get to the step:

$\log(x)^3=27\log(x)$

Let $u= \log(x)$

and solve cubic:  $ u^3 - 27u = 0$

so that: $u(u^2 - 27)$=0

therefore: $u(u-\sqrt{27})(u + \sqrt{27})= 0$

Now find the roots then resubstitute $\log(x) = u$; to get the answer

Comment: seems a similar answer was already posted!